# Asterisk do not detect busy tone on mobile call

Tags: asterisk

I need a help on my asterisk project.

I have already set up an ivr for my company using asterisk.
 server configurations are:
 asterisk 10.0

- digium TE121
- E1 PRI from reliance communication india.

My problem is that when someone calls on my ivr number he/she will be diverted to a mobile/landline number as per the dtmf input they give.

When I redirect it to the landline number, the busy/noanswer state is detected perfectly and the dialstatus variable is being set. But when I redirect it to the mobile number, the busy state is not detected and Asterisk shows it as ringing until the dial timeout is reached.

The problem is that in India on landline numbers, the tones are defined by the international telecom authority and are given immediately. But on mobile numbers, the operator plays a voice file first instead of giving the busy tone. And then gives the busy tone after about 20 seconds. So Asterisk does not detect the busy tone on mobile numbers.

So if there is an technique or pathc to solve this problem, please let me know. Is there any solution using AFI/AMI scripting then it will be appriciated.

My ivr dialplan is as given below: I have changed the extention number for privacy issues.

```
exten => _2121212,1,GotoIfTime(10:00-19:00,mon-sat,*,*?2121212,2:2121212,4)
exten => _2121212,2,Background(ive1new)
exten => _2121212,3,WaitExten(15)

exten => _2121212,4,Playback(officehours1)
exten => _2121212,5,WaitExten(3)
exten => _2121212,6,Goto(3090700,4)

exten => 0,1,Dial(DAHDI/g2/<mobilenumber here>,30)
exten => 0,2,Goto(2121212-${DIALSTATUS},1)

exten => 1,1,Dial(DAHDI/g2/<mobilenumber here>,20,r)
exten => 1,n,Goto(2121212-${DIALSTATUS},1)

exten => 2,1,Dial(DAHDI/g2/<mobilenumber here>,20,r)
exten => 2,n,Goto(2121212-${DIALSTATUS},1)

exten => 3,1,Dial(DAHDI/g2/<mobilenumber here>,20,r)
exten => 3,n,Goto(2121212-${DIALSTATUS},1)

exten => 9,1,Goto(2121212,2)

exten => 2121212-NOANSWER,1,Dial(DAHDI/g2/<mobilenumber here>,20,r)
exten => 2121212-NOANSWER,2,hangup()

exten => 2121212-BUSY,1,Dial(DAHDI/g2/<mobilenumber here>,20,r)
exten => 2121212-BUSY,2,hangup()

exten => 2121212-CONGESTION,1,Dial(DAHDI/g2/<mobilenumber here>,20,r)
exten => 2121212-CONGESTION,2,hangup()

exten => 2121212-CHANUNAVAIL,1,Dial(DAHDI/g2/<mobilenumber here>,20,r)
exten => 2121212-CHANUNAVAIL,2,hangup()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with AGI 
simply dial the number set a time out and check the dialstatus 
is statis !=ANSWER 
switch to another extension or DIAL another number

Comment: i want to perform action on BUSY status. and asterisk is not setting BUSY status when i am dialing mobile number and the mobile number is busy.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding was that noises (including speech) before the busy signal would not matter much, so I wonder if the problem instead is that the busy tones are simply not the usual ones, but have a different pitch or timing, and thus are they not detected.  I am pretty sure that happens with mobile providers where I live.

In the chan_dahd.conf file there is a variable called "busypattern" that you can fiddle with.  I